# SQL Server 2008 Service Broker to MQTT Mosquitto Broker

Tags: sql-server, mqtt, service-broker

We have an old SQL Server 2008 system that needs to communicate to our MQTT broker (Mosquitto).
We intend to use trigger method as outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-service-broker?view=sql-server-ver16)

However I do not know enough about enabling the SQL Service Broker, what do I need to get the SQL Service Broker to communicate to the Mosquito Broker.

What do we need besides the SQL Service Broker enabled?

So for example I have a trigger somewhat like the example in the web page

```
DECLARE @dialog_handle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;

BEGIN DIALOG @dialog_handle  
FROM insertedData
TO SERVICE 'MosquitoService';  
SEND ON CONVERSATION @dialog_handle (@Message) ;
```

How can we accomplish this ?
We do not need SQL server to receive messages , we only need to publish messages ..

Comment: Service Broker (SB) is just a queue (albeit one that's backed by a transactional RDBMS). What you show above is how to put messages in the queue. In the same docs, they outline how to get messages out of the queue in [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-service-broker?view=sql-server-ver16#processing-messages). SB won't reach out to your MSQTT but rather MSQTT should pull messages from SB. Is there a particular part of that process that you're stuck on?

Comment: MQTT brokers do **NOT** pull anything. There would need to be a separate  MQTT Client that reads the queue and then publish to the MQTT broker.

Comment: @hardillb I was thinking the SQL Service Broker would publish to my broker. I am guessing that is not the case, if not then what do I need to accomplish a publish from the SQL Service Broker to the MQTT broker

Comment: @BenThul I was thinking the SQL Service Broker would publish to my broker. I am guessing that is not the case, if not then what do we need to accomplish a publish from the SQL Service Broker to the MQTT broker.

Comment: Like I said, you don't. @hardillb implies that there needs to be something in between SB and MQTT to pull from the former and push to the latter. I, unfortunately, don't have any experience there and so am of little to no help.

Comment: You are probably going to need to write (or find) some .net code to deploy as a custom function, but SQL Server isn't my bag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a program that reads from the queue backing MosquitoService and writes to MQTT.

Here's an old sample of how to read from Service Broker in .NET: https://github.com/microsoftarchive/msdn-code-gallery-community-s-z/tree/master/Service%20Broker%20Message%20Processor%20Service%20Sample

Comment: So I am going to need to read from the SQL broker, then write my own publisher to publish to the MQTT broker - does that sum it up?

Comment: Yep.  That’s correct.